# Firebase emulator local debugging with language other than javascript/typescript

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have successfully deployed and tested firebase functions by deploying c#. My question is that when i set up local emulator it only allows me to choose between javascript and typescript? Shouldn't the emulator support all languages that firebase allows users to deploy with?

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) and tools only support JavaScript-based deployment and testing.  All of its code is written for nodejs, which run JavaScript only.

If you [deployed something written in C#](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-dotnet), then you didn't use any Firebase tools at all.  The [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) product is primarily part of GCP, and you likely used the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) to deploy them.  Firebase provides an entirely different thing.  It just adds tool and SDKs on top of the core Cloud Functions product.  (Note that "Firebase Functions" isn't really a product at all - you'll not see that term anywhere in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).  Firebase's additions to Cloud Functions are referred to as "Cloud Functions for Firebase".)

If you want to continue working with Cloud Functions in a language other than what's supported by the Firebase CLI, then you'll have to find other tools for that.

I suggest reading: [Firebase & Google Cloud: What’s different with Cloud Functions?](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb)

Comment: Yes i used gcloud CLI to deploy my functions. Thank you for your reply.